# How to get the closing time of day in timing schedule that spans multiple days

Tags: c#, sql, ef-core-5.0

Assume I have the following table called **Timing**:

[image]

Obviously each row represents a shift in a specific day.

A day can have non-overlapping multiple shifts.

If a shift spans the next day it will be splitted at midnight, and the second half would have a parent id of the first half (as you can see in row 24 and 31)

I want to query how many minutes until my day ends (the next closing time).

For instance if I'm at day 1, my day ends at **day 2 - 2:00 AM** (because the shift starts at **day 1 - 9:00**, and ends at **day 2 - 2:00**).

I have to be careful if there are gaps (like weekends or so). Notice there is no day 3, so the next closing time would be **day 4 - 23:15** (provided that you are at day 3).

I'm mainly looking for a Linq query (Timing.Where(x=> x.close_time< .... etc).

But I'm thinking that it might be super complicated, so I'm ok with having a raw SQL query.

EDIT:
This is what I got so far:

```
    var localTime = DateTime.Now;
    var tomorrowDay = ((int)localTime.DayOfWeek + 7 + 1) % 7;

    Timing lastShift = Timings.Where(x =>
              ((int)x.DayOfWeek) == tomorrowDay && x.ParentId != null)
              .SingleOrDefault(); // Either it is tomorrow but starts today.

    if (lastShift != null)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32((lastShift.CloseTime - localTime.TimeOfDay).TotalMinutes);
    }

    lastShift = Timings
              .Where(x => x.DayOfWeek == localTime.DayOfWeek && x.CloseTime >= localTime.TimeOfDay)
              .OrderByDescending(x => x.CloseTime)
              .Take(1).SingleOrDefault();

    return Convert.ToInt32((lastShift.CloseTime - localTime.TimeOfDay).TotalMinutes);
```

**EDIT**:

Thanks to @Han, here is a list of the same table above:

```
    var Timings = new []
    {
        new Timing(22, (DayOfWeek)0, new TimeSpan(9,45,0), new TimeSpan(11, 15,  0),null),
        new Timing(23, (DayOfWeek)0, new TimeSpan(13,  0,  0), new TimeSpan( 15,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(24, (DayOfWeek)1, new TimeSpan( 9,  0,  0), new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59), null),
        new Timing(31, (DayOfWeek)2, new TimeSpan( 0,  0,  0), new TimeSpan( 2,  0,  0), 24),
        new Timing(25, (DayOfWeek)2, new TimeSpan(10,  0,  0), new TimeSpan(12,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(26, (DayOfWeek)2, new TimeSpan(15,  0,  0), new TimeSpan(17,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(28, (DayOfWeek)4, new TimeSpan( 9, 45,  0), new TimeSpan(23, 15,  0), null),
        new Timing(29, (DayOfWeek)5, new TimeSpan( 9, 45,  0), new TimeSpan(23, 15,  0), null),
        new Timing(30, (DayOfWeek)6, new TimeSpan( 9, 45,  0), new TimeSpan(23, 15,  0), null),
    };

class Timing
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek {get; set;}
    public TimeSpan OpenTime {get; set;}
    public TimeSpan CloseTime {get; set;}
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}
    
    public Timing(int id, DayOfWeek dow, TimeSpan openTime, TimeSpan closeTime, int? parentId)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.DayOfWeek = dow;
        this.OpenTime = openTime;
        this.CloseTime = closeTime;
        this.ParentId = parentId;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Han no problem, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to left self-join your table to get the close time in the next day. I assume **each row has zero or one child row**. I don't use table but array, but the query should be the same. I code in LINQPad.

```
void Main()
{
    var Timings = new []
    {
        new Timing(22, 0, new DateTime(2021,  9, 12,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 12, 11, 15,  0), null),
        new Timing(23, 0, new DateTime(2021,  9, 12, 13,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 12, 15,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(24, 1, new DateTime(2021,  9, 13,  9,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 13, 23, 59, 59), null),
        new Timing(31, 2, new DateTime(2021,  9, 14,  0,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 14,  2,  0,  0), 24),
        new Timing(25, 2, new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 10,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 12,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(26, 2, new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 15,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 17,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(28, 4, new DateTime(2021,  9, 16,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 16, 23, 15,  0), null),
        new Timing(29, 5, new DateTime(2021,  9, 17,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 17, 23, 15,  0), null),
        new Timing(30, 6, new DateTime(2021,  9, 18,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 18, 23, 15,  0), null),
    };
    
    var timingGroupedWithChildren = (
        from t1 in Timings.Where(x => x.ParentId == null) // parent rows only
        join t2 in Timings.Where(x => x.ParentId != null) // childr rows only
            on t1.Id equals t2.ParentId // left join parent's Id with child's ParentId
            into nextDay
        select new {t1, nextDay})
        .Dump() //unremark this line to get show the result in LINQPad
        ;
}

class Timing
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int DayOfWeek {get; set;}
    public DateTime OpenTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime CloseTime {get; set;}
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}
    
    public Timing(int id, int dow, DateTime openTime, DateTime closeTime, int? parentId)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.DayOfWeek = dow;
        this.OpenTime = openTime;
        this.CloseTime = closeTime;
        this.ParentId = parentId;
    }
}
```

The timingGroupedWithChildren looks like this:
[image]

Notice that only id = 24 has nextDay, the other rows don't have nextDay. There are 8 items (shown at top left corner), but only Id 23 and 24 are shown in detail (other rows are collapsed to save space because my screen is not large enough).

Now it's easy to get the closing time in next day. First approach is like this.

```
void Main()
{
    var Timings = new []
    {
        new Timing(22, 0, new DateTime(2021,  9, 12,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 12, 11, 15,  0), null),
        new Timing(23, 0, new DateTime(2021,  9, 12, 13,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 12, 15,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(24, 1, new DateTime(2021,  9, 13,  9,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 13, 23, 59, 59), null),
        new Timing(31, 2, new DateTime(2021,  9, 14,  0,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 14,  2,  0,  0), 24),
        new Timing(25, 2, new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 10,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 12,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(26, 2, new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 15,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 17,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(28, 4, new DateTime(2021,  9, 16,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 16, 23, 15,  0), null),
        new Timing(29, 5, new DateTime(2021,  9, 17,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 17, 23, 15,  0), null),
        new Timing(30, 6, new DateTime(2021,  9, 18,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 18, 23, 15,  0), null),
    };
    
    var timingGroupedWithChildren = (
        from t1 in Timings.Where(x => x.ParentId == null) // parent rows only
        join t2 in Timings.Where(x => x.ParentId != null) // childr rows only
            on t1.Id equals t2.ParentId // left join parent's Id with child's ParentId
            into nextDay
        select new {
            t1.Id,
            t1.DayOfWeek,
            t1.OpenTime,
            // if current row's next day is null, then use current row's CloseTime
            // otherwise use next day's CloseTime
            CloseTime = nextDay.Where(x => x.ParentId == t1.Id).Count() == 0 ? t1.CloseTime : nextDay.Where(x => x.ParentId == t1.Id).Single().CloseTime
        })
        //.Dump() //unremark this line to get show the result in LINQPad
        ;
    
    var myShift = timingGroupedWithChildren.Where(x => x.Id == 24).Single();
    var myWorkingHours = (myShift.CloseTime - myShift.OpenTime).TotalHours;
    Console.WriteLine($"Working hours = {myWorkingHours}");
}

class Timing
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int DayOfWeek {get; set;}
    public DateTime OpenTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime CloseTime {get; set;}
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}
    
    public Timing(int id, int dow, DateTime openTime, DateTime closeTime, int? parentId)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.DayOfWeek = dow;
        this.OpenTime = openTime;
        this.CloseTime = closeTime;
        this.ParentId = parentId;
    }
}
```

You can see in pic below that I substitute the closing day if current row has children. But I don't test this query with an actual database (I'm using an array) and I don't like calling nextDay.Where(x => ...).Count() twice because some methods in LINQ, eg. Count(), iterates all rows. It's filtered with Where(x => ...) but I can't' say anything unless I see the actual SQL statement executed when calling this query. You can see the actual statement if you turn on SQL Profiler in SQL Management Studio or use LINQPad SQL translation. The button is at the top in the pic (Result lambda symbol SQL IL Tree).

[image]

Another approach is just take the child row and do the Count() after you fetch from SQL.

```
void Main()
{
    var Timings = new []
    {
        new Timing(22, 0, new DateTime(2021,  9, 12,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 12, 11, 15,  0), null),
        new Timing(23, 0, new DateTime(2021,  9, 12, 13,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 12, 15,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(24, 1, new DateTime(2021,  9, 13,  9,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 13, 23, 59, 59), null),
        new Timing(31, 2, new DateTime(2021,  9, 14,  0,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 14,  2,  0,  0), 24),
        new Timing(25, 2, new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 10,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 12,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(26, 2, new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 15,  0,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 14, 17,  0,  0), null),
        new Timing(28, 4, new DateTime(2021,  9, 16,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 16, 23, 15,  0), null),
        new Timing(29, 5, new DateTime(2021,  9, 17,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 17, 23, 15,  0), null),
        new Timing(30, 6, new DateTime(2021,  9, 18,  9, 45,  0), new DateTime(2021,  9, 18, 23, 15,  0), null),
    };
    
    var timingGroupedWithChildren = (
        from t1 in Timings.Where(x => x.ParentId == null) // parent rows only
        join t2 in Timings.Where(x => x.ParentId != null) // childr rows only
            on t1.Id equals t2.ParentId // left join parent's Id with child's ParentId
            into nextDay
        select new {
            t1.Id,
            t1.DayOfWeek,
            t1.OpenTime,
            t1.CloseTime,
            NextDay = nextDay
        })
        //.Dump() //unremark this line to get show the result in LINQPad
        ;
        
    var myShift = timingGroupedWithChildren.Where(x => x.Id == 24).Single();
    var myWorkingHours = ((myShift.NextDay.Count() == 0 ? myShift.CloseTime : myShift.NextDay.Single().CloseTime) - myShift.OpenTime).TotalHours;
    Console.WriteLine($"Working hours = {myWorkingHours}");
}

class Timing
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int DayOfWeek {get; set;}
    public DateTime OpenTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime CloseTime {get; set;}
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}
    
    public Timing(int id, int dow, DateTime openTime, DateTime closeTime, int? parentId)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.DayOfWeek = dow;
        this.OpenTime = openTime;
        this.CloseTime = closeTime;
        this.ParentId = parentId;
    }
}
```

You can see that only row with Id = 24 has NextDay (like pic #1).
[image]

Comment: First, let me thank you a lot for going this far and having all these snippets, experiments, screenshots, and elaborations to help a stranger.
I feel saying thank you is not enough, so I'm gonna start a bounty and award it to you.

Comment: Second, I'm not sure about this, but I feel we are relying on the order of the shifts in case there are multiple ones on the same day.
I think I can add OrderBy to the shifts in a day, and take the last one (in case no child for them is present)

Comment: One more thing, OpenTime, and CloseTime are actually TimeSpan not DateTime. So it is not a specific date, it is a schedule that applies for every week.
EDIT: I added the correct class structure along with a sample array (inspired by your solution)

Comment: @Nour, I left self-join using the current row Id = any row ParentId. DoW 2 has 3 rows but it points to the correct ParentId. So Id 24 is the parent of Id 31.

Comment: I actually have to start a bounty (after two days from asking and not approving an answer). Once the bounty is started, I have to accept an answer and it will be awarded the bounty.
So tomorrow I can start the bounty.

Comment: No problem. Do I need to do anything?

Comment: For the (left self-join), what about for instance day 0? It has two rows and I need the last one to be selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237123/discussion-between-han-and-nour).